# How to access image_name from mysql database for an array of 8 session images

Tags: php, mysql

Noobie here, apologies if the question is silly.....

I have an array of 8 images used in a session. These images are fetched randomly from the directory using the following code.

gameply.php:

```
<?php

 session_start();
 $dire="Annotated Dataset/images/";
 $images = glob($dire. '*.{jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE);
 shuffle($images);
 $images=array_slice($images,0,8);
 $_SESSION['images']=$images;

 ?>
```

I have the names of all the images from the directory stored in the database table "images". Now i want to display these 8 images from the session as a Gallery with help of mysql, by referring the name of the images from the table. I tried using the following code:

```
 <?php

  session_start();

  $galleryimg= $_SESSION['images'];

  $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');

  for($galleryimg as $key) {

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM images
    WHERE image_name = '$key'
    ORDER BY image_id DESC";

   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   }

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $results_array['data'][$counter] = array ("image" => $row['image_name'], 
  "scenario" => $row['scenario'],  "verified" => $row['verified']);
 $counter++;
 }
```

I think there is some mistake with the query. Can some one tell me how to access the image_name of the array of session images using Sql query.

the table has:

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It may help if you show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE images;` so we can tell what's in that table.

Comment: Also `fetch` is missing: `$result->fetch_row()` or something similar.

Comment: @O.Jones i have added the picture of my table

Comment: @freeek i have edited the code.. Can you check now

Comment: You will get only last image information like this. Is this your problem?

Comment: You could use where \`name\` in () syntax in your query. Inside the loop, create a list of image names to use in a query after the loop, that way you only have one query.

Comment: @freeek i need to get the image name of the 8 images used in the session from the table

Comment: @Uviiii please try my answer and tell me if it works for your database.

Comment: @user2342558 i tried your code, its not working still.

Comment: @Uviiii what's the error occurring?

Comment: @user2342558 it doesnt show any error, thats weird . Also It doesnt show the images.

Comment: @Uviiii please post here the result of echo `$sql; and of print_r($result);`

Answer (score 0):

the $result = $conn->query($sql); has nothing to do with your code.
I see mixed usage of mysqli and PDO. It will never work. By the way, query looks good.
My advise is to read proper PDO syntax and start using PDO not mysqli.
Second advise is not to run queries in a loop unless people are dying.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php That function is correct.

Comment: True, I did check the code as it is now and it looks OK, but the query loop is wrong or I completely fail to understand the workflow. It will be nice to see the output you get or expand a little the question.

Comment: The loop is wrong, yes. Not for the reasons you wrote, but because (as I state in my answer) the variable `$result` has a new, different value after each iteration of the loop. At the end, only the last "image" is stored into `$result` and stored in `$results_array['data']`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Disclaimer**: this answer assumes that there's a successful connection to the database.

The problem is here:

```php
for($galleryimg as $key) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images
    WHERE image_name = '$key'
    ORDER BY image_id DESC";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
```

Your `$result` will have a new value everytime you iterate `$gallleryimg`, because you're overwritting the variable.

Please, use prepared statements to run the same query *n* times.
It is a lot more efficient (for repeated queries) and you can fetch right after you do the query.

However, it is harder to learn and get the ball going, but it is very useful.

---

Also, this line (with better indentation):

```php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $results_array['data'][$counter] = array(
        "image" => $row['image_name'], 
        "scenario" => $row['scenario'],
        "verified" => $row['verified']
    );

    $counter++;
}
```

You don't need the `$counter` for anything.
Just do `$results_array['data'][] = array( ... );`

Comment: @Uviiii Yes, because my code is *your* code. I didn't change anything. I didn't re-implement anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is you code with some optimizations.

```
session_start();

$galleryImgs = $_SESSION['images'];

if(!$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=registration', 'root', $pass))
{
    die("Error connecting to database.");
}

$imagesIN = "'".join("', '", array_map(function($v) { return str_replace("'", "''", $v); }, $galleryImgs))."'";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM images
WHERE image_name IN ($imagesIN)
ORDER BY image_id DESC";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

$results_array = array('data' => array());
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $results_array['data'][] = array
    (
        "image"    => $row['image_name'], 
        "scenario" => $row['scenario'],
        "verified" => $row['verified']
    );
}
```

- check for connection error
- the `$counter` variable isn't needed because with `[]` you can create a new entry for the array that automatically get the next index
- with [`join`](https://www.php.net/join) you can perform a single query to get all images data
- with [array_map](https://www.php.net/array_map) I sanitize the array for eventual `'` char that may cause `SQL injection` / errors
- some indentation
- variable name change for `galleryimg` in `galleryImgs`: with camelcase name you can improve readability

Comment: You are misusing prepared statements. Also, your code has a potential for SQL Injection vulnerabilities. You don't know what's in `$_SESSION['images']` and where it came from.

Comment: there is the `prepare`... about the $_SESSION['images'] it's set by script, not passed by user with $_GET or $_POST

Comment: It comes from a `glob()`. A file name with `'` is perfectly fine. It can happen.

Comment: ahh yes, it may be in the file name... rarely but yes. I'll edi t my answer thanks

Comment: Please use `function($v)use(&$link){ return $link->real_escape_string($v); }` instead. This is the correct way to escape character sequences. There are edge-cases that `$link->real_escape_string` protects against.

Comment: but `real_escape_string` works only if the database/php is properly configured. In my hosting `real_escape_string` does nothing, so I need to escape them manually and by doing this it's always worked.

Comment: That's weird. The only thing I can think of is if there's a problem with the character encoding information being sent to the server (like, not calling [`mysqli_set_charset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) or something). That's something I've personally never seen. Seeing as it is an important function for your database safety, I would investigate why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the loop and multiple SQL queries by using the IN clause in your where. Since the $galleryimg is 
already an array, using implode to get a list of if image names for the IN clause is easy ising the implode function.

Also, if you are using a limited set of column values, don't use *, but list only the column names you need.

You can also eliminate the counter, using [] instead.

```
<?php

session_start();

$galleryimg= $_SESSION['images'];

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');

$sql = "SELECT
    `image_name`,
    `scenario`,
    `verified`
FROM `images`
WHERE `image_name` in '".implode("','",$galleryimg)."')
ORDER BY `image_id` DESC";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $results_array['data'][] = 
        array("image" => $row['image_name'],
            "scenario" => $row['scenario'],
            "verified" => $row['verified']);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injections. The array `$_SESSION['images']` has unknown data from an unknown source.